# Using an IEnumerable<Anonymous Type> within Dynamic Type View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
var s = myInventoryEntities.p_Forms().Select(i => new  { i.Customer, i.Order_ID }).Distinct().ToList();

ViewBag.MyData = s;

return View();
```

this gives me

```
    { Customer = "Bob", Order_ID = 2644550 }
```

In my razor code

i traverse the data

```
@foreach ( var x in @ViewBag.MyData){
x.Customer // Does not exist! :(
}
```

Please help!

'object' does not contain a definition for 'Customer'

Comment: do you need the `@` before x?  Wouldn't it just be `x`?

Comment: @DavidHoerster: No you need that in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewBag data's life time is very limited. Are you sure you are coming to this view from the same action method where you set the ViewBag data ?

Suggestion : Try to Avoid Dynamic types liek ViewData/ViewBag. Sticking to Strongly typed makes your code much better readable/ maintainable.

If your Domain object and What you want to display is same, do not bother about creating a ViewModel. else create a viewmodel

```
public class CustomerOrder
{
  public string CustomerName
  public int OrderID { set;get;}
  //other properties as relevant (to the view)
}
```

and return that instead of the ViewBag

```
public ActionResult GetOrders()
{

  var s = myInventoryEntities.p_Forms().
          Select(i => new  CustomerOrder {
                                           CustomerName= i.Customer, 
                                           OrderID=i.Order_ID
                                         }).Distinct().ToList();
  return View(s);
}
```

And in the view

```
@model IList<CustomerOrder>
@foreach ( var x in Model)
{
   <p>@x.Customer</p>
}
```