# How to pass an Enumerable model to view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

firstly, i have a model which is a view model i created specially for views, that is not real model map to table like below:

Model:

```
 public class BlogPageModel
    {
        public Blog Blogs { get; set; }
        public BlogAid BlogAids { get; set; }
        public BlogAuthor BlogAuthors { get; set; }
        public BlogComment BlogComments { get; set; }
        public BlogContent BlogContents { get; set; }
        public BlogNews BlogNews { get; set; }
        public BlogTitle BlogTitles { get; set; }
    }
```

but you can see that all properties in this model is real model map to table, so i use it to display my view content.

and the other hand, i have a view which is a page to show all blogs for authors of blog, who should be the blog owner. so it is something like below:

View:

```
@model  IEnumerable<LeduInfo.Models.BlogPageModel> 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div class="container">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1 class="page-header">Blog Home 1 <small>Blog Homepage</small></h1>
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">Blog Home 1</li>
          </ol>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-8">

           @foreach (var item in Model)
           {


            <h1>@*<a href="blog-post.html">A Blog Home Template for Bootstrap 3</a>*@
              @Html.ActionLink(item.BlogTitles.Titles,"BlogPost",new{@id=item.Blogs.BlogID})
          </h1>
          <p class="lead">by <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a></p>
          <hr>
          <p><i class="icon-time"></i> Posted on August 28, 2013 at 10:00 PM</p>
          <hr>
          <a href="blog-post.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x300" class="img-responsive"></a>
          <hr>
          <p>This is a very basic starter template for a blog homepage. It makes use of Font Awesome icons that are built into the 'Modern Business' template, and it makes use of the Bootstrap 3 pager at the bottom of the page.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="blog-post.html">Read More <i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>

          <hr>
           }
```

and my question is how can i make the model Enumerable and return the model.tolist() then send back to view for display?

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<BlogPageModel> modelList = new List<BlogPageModel>();
            BlogPageModel blogpagemodel;
            var blogPageModelList = from b in DB.Blogtbl
                                    join t in DB.BlogTitletbl on b.TitleID equals t.TitleID
                                    join c in DB.BlogContenttbl on b.ContentID equals c.ContentID
                                    where b.BlogID > 0
                                    select new { Title = t.Titles, Content = c.Contents, id = b.BlogID };
            ?????
            return View();
        }
```

do you have any good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am sorry for i don't know what your query return  values.  but i will post sample codes

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<BlogPageModel> modelList = new List<BlogPageModel>();
            modelList.Blogs.Add(//Blogs table values);
            modelList.BlogAid.Add(//BlogAid table values);
            modelList.BlogAuthor.Add(//BlogAuthor table values);

            List<BlogPageModel> modelListLatest = new List<BlogPageModel>();
            return View(modelListLatest.AddRange(modelList));
        }
```

Comment: even this is not detailed about how to add, but i think it help me open my mind, thans.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Linq query [returns an anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889427/using-an-ienumerableanonymous-type-within-dynamic-type-view), so you can't write the name of that type into your View in order to then access it in a strongly-typed manner. If you select a `BlogPageModel` instead you can return an enumerable like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var blogPageModelList = (
        from b in DB.Blogtbl
        join t in DB.BlogTitletbl on b.TitleID equals t.TitleID
        join c in DB.BlogContenttbl on b.ContentID equals c.ContentID
        where b.BlogID > 0
        select new BlogPageModel
        {
            BlogTitles = t.Titles,
            BlogContents = c.Contents
        })
        .ToList();

    return View(blogPageModelList);
}
```

That should work with your view as it is written in your question.

Comment: i am afraid it doesn't work, actually i tried it before, but got below error:

Answer (score 0):

althrough i got one answer to open my mind, but i'd like to post the correct and detailed one on how i solved my issue as well.

```
 IQueryable<BlogPageModel> blogmodellist =     from b in DB.Blogtbl
                                    join t in DB.BlogTitletbl on b.TitleID equals t.TitleID
                                    join c in DB.BlogContenttbl on b.ContentID equals c.ContentID
                                    //join m in DB.BlogCommenttbl on b.CommentID equals m.CommentID
                                    where b.BlogID > 0 && t.Titles !=null
                                    select new BlogPageModel { BlogTitles = t , BlogContents = c, Blogs=b};

            blogpagemodel.Blogs = new Blog();
            blogpagemodel.BlogTitles = new Models.BlogTitle();
            blogpagemodel.BlogContents = new BlogContent();
            //IEnumerable<BlogPageModel> titleList = blogPageModelList.TakeWhile(m => m.Title != null);

            foreach (var item in blogmodellist)
            {
                //blogpagemodel.BlogComments.CommentID = (int)item.cid;
                blogpagemodel.Blogs.BlogID = item.Blogs.BlogID;
                blogpagemodel.BlogTitles.Titles = item.BlogTitles.Titles;
                blogpagemodel.BlogContents.Contents = item.BlogContents.Contents;

                modelList.Add(blogpagemodel);
            }

            //var titlesList = blogPageModelList
            //        .Select(m => m.Title)
            //        .ToList();

            //modelList.AddRange(blogPageModelList.ToList());
            return View(blogmodellist.ToList());
```